# Trying to find a specific set of MACs from a file

Tags: python, python-re

I have been trying to find a specific set of MAC addresses from a file. Basically the MAC starts with 34:D2:62 and continuous with a random arrangement of numbers. This is what I have come up with but it is incorrect:

```
results = re.compile(r'34:D2:62\.[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\.[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\.[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}')
MAC=re.findall(results,string)
```

Basically I want to find all the MACs that are of the type: 34:D2:62:..:..:.. I am still figuring out the re package and it has been quite some trouble! I feel like I am a mile away from the right answer...
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How are the MAC addresses formatted in the file? Can you just search for lines that begin with `34:D2:62`? That would be much simpler.

Comment: If you dont care about whether its a number or character you are looking for, simply use `.` as a 1-character placeholder. What about `re.compile("34:D2:62:..:..:..")` ?

Comment: mnikley's answer worked fine! The file is a txt of a monitor mode scan, it has IPs MACs SSIDs and all those other things in it. re.compile("34:D2:62:..:..:..") worked fine! Thanks a lot!!!